# Transpose the result of dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I use dynamic SQL to run a query:

```
    select @query = '
    SELECT C.LdcCode, ' + @cols + '
    FROM DailyTimesheetUnprocessedCount AS C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #LdcSorting AS S
        ON C.LdcCode = S.LdcCode
    GROUP BY C.LdcCode, S.SortOrder
    ORDER BY ISNULL(S.SortOrder, 100)
    '

    execute(@query)
```

Is there a simple way to transpose the results of the query, so in my case LdcCodes would be column names, and what is now in @cols would be values in the first column?

Thanks.

Comment: Look into [pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pivot).  Tons of questions already on SO about it.

Comment: Here's an example of a dynamic pivot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: Thanks everybody! It works.